# Google Maps API: Directions don't minding if street is one way or not

Tags: api, google-maps, driving-directions, map-directions

I want to draw direction from point A to B to C to D to .....
and I want to see only the map with directions (without text directions next to it)

Problem is if I use **G_TRAVEL_MODE_DRIVING** it displays me directions minding if the street is one way or not.

If I use **G_TRAVEL_MODE_WALKING** it shows me the directions the way I want but this mode requires derectionsPanel in constructor (this is a div element to show directions in textual format)

```
new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);
```

So I'm stuck in here. Suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you make the directionsPanel div invisible?

Comment: yes I did but then I have this: http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/6913/gmapsk.jpg . It is sure better but I would like if I could not have that empty space under page footer. If i set size of the div to 1px it makes no difference because it resizes automatically on size it needs. Hmmm.

Comment: How did you hide it? If you use "display:none" it should not take up any space, see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Also, have you tried just passing null to the 2nd GDirections parameter?

Comment: null parameter is not working. display:none is the right way, thank you!